# Why isn't beautifulsoup displaying the text within a div id?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Currently, I am trying to access the stock price on seeking alpha in [this link](https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/AAPL/income-statement), and the price is within this [HTTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vc0u.png).

This code here should look into the contents of `div id="symbol_last_trade">149.30</div`. But when I run it, the program doesn't output 149.30 as text.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers ={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

url = "https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/AAPL/income-statement"

r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

source = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
price = source.find("div", {"id" : "symbol_last_trade"})
print(price.text)`
```

When I run it, the output is this:

```
div id="symbol_last_trade"></div
```

Does anyone know why this program doesn't output the text within the div?

Answer (score 2):

The data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can use `requests` module to simulate it:

```py
import json
import requests

api_url = "https://finance.api.seekingalpha.com/v2/real-time-prices"
params = {"symbols[]": "aapl"}
data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print("Last price:", data["data"][0]["attributes"]["last"])
```

Prints:

```
Last price: 149.32
```